# HTTP Status: 12002 in .net browser control

Tags: .net, windows, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control, http-status-codes

I am getting HTTP status 12002 while opening my webpage in Browser control inside my desktop application. But its working fine in internet explorer. I am using .NET 3.5.

Error:

> An unknown error occured. Http Status: 12002

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Coming late but hopefully this will help someone else.

After hours of searching I found out that this is an IE client issue. Unfortunately the only answer is to change a local registry setting.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
InternetSettings\ReceiveTimeout
```

Set that to more than 10000 (10 seconds).

Comment: In my case, the key did not exist so I had to add it.  Once I did, I started getting status=200 (I was also originally getting 12002 on Windows Server 2012)